# ImageView - Detecting Image Boundry

Tags: drag-and-drop, imageview, tableview, draggable

I have a tableView with some images in it. I would like to be able to drag these images around the screen. I have created a custom view which is the size of the visible screen that contains an onTouch method handler and also contains onDraw to allow me to drag an image. I would like some opinions on the best way to get the images from the table view and add them to the custom view when the action_down event is triggered (enabling the image to be dragged). Should I add the tableView to the custom view? Would I beable to detect the image boundry?

Thanks

Comment: You'll get more help if you tag your post according to which OS you are talking about.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll remember in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I created onTouchListener for each of the images which created an object that can be passed to the custom view when MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is fired. The custom view is then responsible for redrawing when MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE is fired.